# How can I calculate the area of a triangle only with valid inputs?

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell. I got this question from my assignment. It ask me to make this code work:

```
area_of_triangle :: Float
                 -> Float
                 -> Float
                 -> Maybe Float
```

I know how to do this without `Maybe`; it's like:

```
area_of_triangle :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Float
area_of_triangle a b c = sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c))
  where
     s = (a+b+c)/2
```

I guess the requirement would be if `area_of_triangle=0.0`, return `Nothing` (because such the triangle doesn't exist). But I don't know how to write this.

Comment: You could use an `if` expression to figure out if the result is `0`, if it is, return `Nothing`, otherwise return `Just <the result>`.

Comment: This is not quite correct! Not all choices of `a` `b` and `c` will yield a valid triangle. For example, `area_of_triangle 100000000 1 1`.

Comment: Thanks for @will-sewell comment, I figured out something like this:

    area_of_triangle :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Maybe Float
    area_of_triangle a b c = if area_answer/=0.0
      then Just area_answer
      else Nothing
        where
          area_answer=sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c))
            where
              s = (a+b+c)/2

Something good is now it works perfectly if I input a valid `a`,`b`,`c`. However, if I input invalid number for `a`,`b`,`c`, it returns `Just NaN`.

Now what I'm hoping is it can return `Just (Float)` or `Nothing`, instead of `Just (Float)`or `Just NaN`.

Comment: Just make it easier to read these codes, click here: https://gist.github.com/logeeker/e0dafa987ddab8a21c39

Comment: Some issue with your question: 1) The title should be a valid sentence, not a bunch of tags and pieces of code. A better title could be "How to write a function to comput the area of a triangle with this type?" 2) "doesn't work" has *no meaning* whatsoever. If you get a compiler/runtime error you must copy the *complete* error message in your question. If you get an incorrect result you must provide the input you used, the result you got and what you expected. 3) Adding "please help" and "thanks" is just noise.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your problem, but `Float` is the wrong type for almost anything. If you've learned about type classes, you should accept any type in the `RealFrac` class. If you haven't, you should stick to `Double`. `Float` has little enough precision that it takes very little to make it act peculiarly.

Comment: @SengCheongSong before you do the calculation, check if the input is valid (with another `if` statement), and return `Nothing` if not.

Answer (score 5):

Three lengths can only form a triangle if the sum of each pair of lengths is greater than the other length. In the cases where that is not true, return `Nothing`. Otherwise, you can return `Just a`, where `a` is the length you calculate with your original formula.

```
area_of_triangle :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Float
area_of_triangle a b c = sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c))
  where
     s = (a+b+c)/2

area :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Maybe Float
area a b c
  | ??? = Nothing
  | ??? = Nothing
  | ??? = Nothing
  | otherwise = Just (???)
```

I leave it as an exercise to figure out what Boolean expressions replace the first three `???`s, and what to replace the last `???` with.

Comment: I wrote something like this https://gist.github.com/logeeker/0fa2ee0bd4c1c1a82456 .The codes couldn't load this time. It says https://gist.github.com/logeeker/27a0f813438cc6fdea95

Comment: You aren't passing any arguments to your call to `area_of_triangle_codes`.

Answer (score 0):

I would break this up into three functions:

```
-- | Takes three numbers and indicates
-- whether they can be the lengths of
-- the sides of a (non-degenerate)
-- triangle.
triangleInequality :: (Num a, Ord a)
                   => a -> a -> a -> Bool
triangleInequality x y z
  | ??? &&
    ??? &&
    ??? = ???
  | otherwise = ???

uncheckedArea :: RealFloat a
              => a -> a -> a -> a
uncheckedArea x y z = ???

area :: RealFloat a
     => a -> a -> a -> Maybe a
area x y z
  | ??? = Just ???
  | otherwise = Nothing
```

---

According to [this draft article](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/Triangle.pdf), you can improve the numerical stability of your calculation as follows:

```
area a' b' c'
  | c - (a - b) <= 0 = Nothing
  | otherwise = Just $ 0.25 * sqrt ((a+(b+c)) * (c-(a-b)) * (c+(a-b)) * (a+(b-c)))
  where
    [c, b, a] = sort [a',b',c']
```

However, I don't know that GHC can be trusted to calculate that exactly as written, so some additional care may be required.

Note that you may be better off accepting 0-area "triangles" for some purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out eventually

```
area_of_triangle :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Maybe Float
area_of_triangle x y z
  | x+y>=z && x+z>=y && y+z>=x = Just (sqrt(s*(s-x)*(s-x)*(s-x)))
  | otherwise = Nothing
  where
    s=(x+y+z)/2
```